# Accessing the JavaScript document in Haxe

Tags: javascript, html, haxe

For a "hellow html5-haxe world" test I am trying to print the current URL. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to use the Haxe `js.html.Document` class. The compiler is targeting JS and a `trace("hello world")` works (it is visible in the Chrome developer console).

According to the documentation on this class:

> Each web page loaded in the browser has its own document object. This object serves as an entry point to the web page's content (the DOM tree, including elements such as  and  ) and provides functionality global to the document (such as obtaining the page's URL and creating new elements in the document).

To access the URL there is a `URL` field in the class.

My attempts to get to this class have failed:

```
var url:String = js.html.Document.URL; //does not work, URL is not static.

var tmp = new js.html.Document(); //does not work, this class has no constructor.
var url:String = tmp.URL;
```

In JavaScript `document` is built in to the global namespace and allows us to access the html page. However, Haxe does not seem to have a `document` like object nor a `getDocument()` static function of some JS class.

How can the `js.html.Document` class be accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var doc = js.Browser.window.document;
var url = doc.URL; //or any other document command supported by the browser.
```

This answer was buried in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/y084mee_YDw

Comment: More ways of accessing `js.html.Document` are mentioned in the [api docs](http://api.haxe.org/js/html/Document.html).